# Passing environment variables to NOW

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, next.js, vercel

I am trying to pass firebase environment variables for deployment with `now`.

I have encoded these variables manually with base64 and added them to now with the following command:
`now secrets add firebase_api_key_dev "mybase64string"`
The encoded string was placed within speech marks `""`

These are in my CLI tool and I can see them all using the list command:
`now secrets ls`

```
> 7 secrets found under project-name [499ms]
  name                              created
  firebase_api_key_dev              6d ago
  firebase_auth_domain_dev          6d ago
  ...
```

In my firebase config, I am using the following code:

```
const config = {
  apiKey: Buffer.from(process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY, "base64").toString(),
  authDomain: Buffer.from(process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,"base64").toString(),
  ...
}
```

In my `now.json` file I have the following code:

```
{
  "env": {
    "FIREBASE_API_KEY": "@firebase_api_key_dev",
    "FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN": "@firebase_auth_domain_dev",
    ...
  }
}
```

Everything works fine in my local environment (when I run `next`) as I also have a `.env` file with these variables, yet when I deploy my code, I get the following error in my `now` console:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined

Does this indicate that my environment variables are not being read? What's the issue here? It looks like they don't exist at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to replace my existing `now.json` with:

```
{
  "build":{
    "env": {
      "FIREBASE_API_KEY": "@firebase_api_key",
      "FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN": "@firebase_auth_domain",
      "FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL": "@firebase_database_url",
      "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID": "@firebase_project_id",
      "FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET": "@firebase_storage_bucket",
      "FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID": "@firebase_messaging_sender_id",
      "FIREBASE_APP_ID": "@firebase_app_id",
      "FIREBASE_API_KEY_DEV": "@firebase_api_key_dev",
      "FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN_DEV": "@firebase_auth_domain_dev",
      "FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL_DEV": "@firebase_database_url_dev",
      "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID_DEV": "@firebase_project_id_dev",
      "FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_DEV": "@firebase_storage_bucket_dev",
      "FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID_DEV": "@firebase_messaging_sender_id_dev",
      "FIREBASE_APP_ID_DEV": "@firebase_app_id_dev"
    }
  }  
}
```

I was missing the `build` header.

I had to contact ZEIT support to help me identify this issue.

Comment: Silly mistake from me